# Nginx wildcard path with trailing slash is not working

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I want to create wildcard path that begins with `/blog` folder , I use following code

```
location ~* ^/blog/(.*)$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.php @rewrites;
}

location @rewrites {
    rewrite ^/blog/$ /rewrite/bloguri.php last;
}
```

Following links works , which shows contents of `/rewrite/bloguri.php`

```
http://www.example.com/blog/randomlink.html
http://www.example.com/blog/randomlink
```

but following structures are not working , which i need it to work

```
http://www.example.com/blog/randomlink/
http://www.example.com/blog/randomlink.php
```

Edit :

bloguri.php  contains following contents

```
<?php
echo "blog";
?>
```

Below is screenshot of logs
[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ycdyj.png)

Below is my full nginx.conf

```
 location ~ ^/~(.+?)(/.*?\.php)(/.*)?$ {
     alias /var/www/vhosts/example.com/web_users/$1/$2;
     fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.php)(/?.+)$;
     fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
     fastcgi_pass "unix:///var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/php-fpm.sock";
     include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
 }

 location ~ \.php(/.*)?$ {
     fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.php)(/?.+)$;
     fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
     fastcgi_pass "unix:///var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/php-fpm.sock";
     include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
 }

 location ~ /$ {
     index index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm index.shtml;
 }

 location /blog {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /rewrite/blog.php;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
location /blog {
    index /rewrite/bloguri.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /rewrite/bloguri.php;
}
```

Your question does not state explicitly that you want to redirect all requests to non-existing files to the script, but I assume that is what you are looking for.

This one-liner will do exactly that, and is the standard way of implementing front-controller pattern in nginx.

Comment: I modified my response to simpler approach.

Comment: I hope you have reloaded your nginx configuration after changes. Add the log entries for the requests in your question and add the code of your `bloguri.php` to the question. Also, add all nginx configuration to the question.

Comment: Hi , yes I reloaded ,  I have updated my questions with things you asked

Comment: I added `index` directive. nginx will use the file over there for displaying contents when the URL matches a directory (ending with `/`).